# Partitioning a 128GB SSD and 500GB HDD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, 12.10

So I have a 128GB SSD and 500GB HDD. I want to reïnstall my laptop and put Ubuntu 12.10 on this setup. I already looked around on the internet and came up with this partitioning schema:

- about 2GB of swap on the SSD (I got 4GB of RAM in my laptop)
- / using the rest of that space
- /home on the HDD

So I was wondering, are there any better schemes or extra partitions that I should consider putting on a particular drive?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would read this article about setting up an SSD for ubuntu:

http://www.howtogeek.com/62761/how-to-tweak-your-ssd-in-ubuntu-for-better-performance/

128 gb is an enormous amount of space for /. I have a separate partition for / and /home and my / is well under 16 gb. I think that is probably enough.

You can keep /home on the SSD and link the Downloads, Music and Video folders out to the external HDD

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is have / = 20 GB, /opt = 100 GB, swap = 8 GB on the SSD. Then have the HDD be /home. You really do not need swap if you have more than a gigabyte of RAM unless you are doing something along the lines of Android development or heavy compiling.